# How do I mock a function in a class which is templated?

Tags: c++, googlemock

I am trying to find a way to mock a template function in a class. I also understand that a template function needs to be defined in the header file as well. Can anyone give me a example how do I mock the function ReadData as shown below? Thank you.

```
//foo.hpp
class foo
{
  public: 

  template<typename T>
  T ReadData(int EntryID)
  {
      //do something
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with templates in [some](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md#mocking-class-templates) circumstances, but not in this one(methods), for this, you can use a trip..., specialize your template, [see details by Michael](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/googlemock/5Ssnt9myAUU)