# function object argument deduction with c++17 CTAD

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-argument-deduction, ctad

I have a lot types to use compare functors, and I would like to see if there is way to simplify it without passing the argument. Here is a dummy code example:

```
struct Base{};

template<typename T> struct Compare {
  bool operator()(const T& a, const T& b) {
    return true;
  }
}; 

int main()
{
    Base b1, b2;
    Compare(b1, b2);
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work https://godbolt.org/z/q56c3coaT. But then I wonder how c++17 std::less could work, or there is any way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Your `Compare` does not have to be a template class, just convert its `operator()` into a template function, and create a `constexpr` object for comparison usage.

```
struct Compare {
  template<typename T> 
  constexpr bool operator()(const T& a, const T& b) const {
    return true;
  }
}; 
constexpr inline Compare cmp;
```

Then you can invoke like this:

```
Base b1, b2;
cmp(b1, b2);
```

> But then I wonder how c++17 std::less could work

C++14 adds the default template parameter `void` to `std::less`, and changes the `operator()` of the partial specialization [`std::less<void>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less_void) to template function. Due to the existence of default argument, you can choose not to specify template parameters, but in such case the `operator()` of `std::less<void>` will be used.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I did not mention enough the context behind. I have some code that use this cmp function (actually a free function), and to mock this function with gmock, I wrap it up in a class template and make it virtual. Then I suffer with the problem how to trigger it without providing the argument.

Comment: @pepero: I suggest to ask another question for that (or look for existing ones (maybe that one [how-do-i-mock-a-function-in-a-class-which-is-templated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43532724/how-do-i-mock-a-function-in-a-class-which-is-templated)) )

Comment: @Jarod42, i think they are two different paths, and i still like to see if it is doable with template class, like the std::less, so that the function is easier to mock.